# bash script create users using csv

Tags: linux, bash, csv, passwords, usergroups

I'm trying to create different users from a csv file in bash.
This my code so far:

```
  #create arrays usernames and password 
  groups=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`) 
  usernames=(`cut -d: -f 3  "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |awk '{print substr($1.$2}'`) 
  password=(`cut -d: -f 4 "$filein"`) 
  #creates the user accounts, adds them to groups, and sets passwords 
  #then once account is created 
  #checks if the group exists, if not then creates it 
  for group in ${groups[*]} 
  do 
  grep -q "^$group" /etc/group ; let x=$? 
  if [ $x -eq 1 ] 
  then 
  groupadd "$group" 
  fi 
  done 
  #creates the user accounts, adds them to groups, and sets passwords 
  #then once account is created 
  x=0 
  created=0 
  for user in ${usernames[*]} 
  do 
  useradd -n -c ${usernames[$x]} -g "${groups[$x]}" $user 2> /dev/null 
  chpasswd  "$user" > /dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
  then 
  let created=$created+1 
  fi
```

For some reason, when I run the file, this is the error I get, even went let me add any users 
groupadd: 'Q123456,Bob,Bob,QwertY1' is not a valid group name 
groupadd: 'Q236578,Jane,Jane,AzertY2' is not a valid group name 
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter in cut command is " : " instead of " , "

From cut manpage:

> -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>
> use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

Comment: do you mean   usernames=(`-d,DELIM: -f 3  "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |awk '{print substr($1.$2}'`) ??

Comment: What I mean is:
> cut -d , <the rest of the command>
Every time you use cut in this script
I.e. cut -d , -f 1 "$filein"

Comment: to be honest i new to bash script i dont really fully understand you will look like this ??  usernames=cut -d( -f 3  "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |awk '{print substr($1.$2})

Comment: Those 3 lines should fix the issue
  groups=(`cut -d , -f 1 "$filein"`) 
  usernames=(`cut -d , -f 3  "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |awk '{print substr($1.$2}'`) 
  password=(`cut -d , -f 4 "$filein"`) 
Explanation:
-d switch within cut command is the character on witch to split the fields on.
In your example (CSV) your delimiter is , (comma).

Comment: ok thats make more seance now , i going to try it now thanks and thank you for patient

Comment: If it works i would kindly appreciate if you approved the answer :)

Comment: not yet my linux mint get corrupted i need to install fresh one i will let you know if working or not i really appreciated bro cheers

Comment: no bro didint work test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
test.sh: line 11: `  usernames=(cut -d , -f 2 "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |awk '{print substr($1.$2}')'
test.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Cloud you explain what are you trying to achieve  with " awk '{print substr($1.$2} " ?
Also what do fields 2 and 3 stand for. Code suggests that field 3 is used for username ?

Comment: " awk '{print substr($1.$2} "  is to separate first name and surname with a comma and     "f 2" and "f 3 "is to read column 2 and 3 i dont really need them this is my csv file look like   'Q123456,Bob,Bob,QwertY1' so i want to ready "bob.bob " as username an "QwertY1 " will be the password the group is private but its not necessary  if you have a different solution i will appropriated

Comment: This line should work then
usernames=(`cut -d , -f 2,3  "$1" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed -r s/,/./`)
It takes fileds 2 and 3 and converts ' , ' into ' . '
Result beeing bob.bob

Comment: no that still give me an error  "  test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
test.sh: line 10: `  usernames=(cut -d , -f 2,3 "$1" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed -r s/,/./)'  "

Comment: for some reason when i add this quote ' create 1 account but still give me error                  " Welcome! Your account has been created.  Your username is cut -d , -f 2,3 "$1" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed -r s/,/./ and password is "cut" without the quotes.
Complete. 1 accounts have been created.  "

Comment: You are probably missing the ' ` ' characters around that cut -d , -f 2,3 "$1" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed -r s/,/./ statement. StackOverflow uses them as code blocks so you have to enter them manually